# Rotated camera input in Kivy

Tags: android, python, camera, kivy

I'm trying to show the user the live preview stream from thier camera using the Camera object which comes with Kivy. When the frame of the camera is a ScatterLayout everything is fine but the position is not stable (and we'd generally not like to use the ScatterLayout). When using GridLayout the position becomes stable (over different devices) but the preview stream is rotated by 90 degrees on Android devices (on my laptop everything shows just fine)

Any thoughts and ideas?

The constructor calls (as the names suggests, the CroppedCamera class does nothing but cropping the frame. Removing it doesn't change the problem):

```
self.camera = CroppedCamera(index=0, resolution=(1280, 720), rotation=camRot, ratio=imgRatio, imageBox=self)
    self.add_widget(self.camera.outer)

class CroppedCamera(Camera):
  def __init__(self, ratio, imageBox, rotation, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CroppedCamera, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.outer = GridLayout()
    self.outer.rows = 1
    self.outer.cols = 1
    self.imageBox = imageBox
    self.outer.add_widget(self)
    self.outer.rotation = rotation
    self.outer.pos_hint = {'x': 0, 'y': -0.3}
    self.outer.size_hint = (0.8, 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rotation seems to only work using the ScatterLayout, as this is part of the functionalities this layout brings. In order to only rotate, but to disable user interaction (drag, zoom, rotation, etc), one can simply disable them by setting something like:

```
ScatterLayout(do_scale=False, do_translation_x=False, do_translation_y=False, do_rotation=False)
```